# javascript, user clicks too fast

Tags: javascript, click

i'm new to javascript, and i'm trying to build some kind of memory game.
the game works fine until the user clicks too fast on the cards and more than 2 cards are "open".
the function is activated by clicking. i tried to check if the function is already active by adding a global var, set it to 1 ( function busy) at entrance and set it back to 0 (free) at the end. it didn't work.
any ideas how to solve it?
code is:

```js
var isProcessed =0;

function cardClicked(elCard){
  //check to see if another click is being processed
  if(isProcessed===1){
    return;
  }
  //if function is not already active - set it to "active" and continue
  isProcessed=1;
  
  
  //doing all kind of stuff
  
  //setting function to "free" again
  isProcessed=0;

}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem unless the function is doing something asynchronous. What does it do?

Comment: you can disable the button when it is clicked and enable later when needed

Comment: how do i disable the buttons of the rest of the cards?
all of the divs of the cards has onclick. how to remover them/add them back while the program is running?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem with your code is that when you call the function it both processes and frees the card currently being clicked which allows other cards to be clicked as well.

A simple way to fix it is: (I'm assuming after two cards are clicked it will "close" and others will be available)

```js
var isProcessed =0;
var selectedPair=[];
function cardClicked(elCard){
  //add to the amount of cards processed
  isProcessed++;
  //If there are two cards "processed" then:
  if(isProcessed===2){
    //reset the amount processed after two cards have been opened
    isProcessed=0;
    //"close" card functionality
    //clear the array of selected cards;
    selectedPair=[];
    return;
  }else{
    //add card to the selectedPair array so we can keep track
    //which two cards to "close" after it resets
    selectedPair.push(elCard);
    //do all kinds of stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plan should work. As @JustLearning mentioned in the comment, it might be better to to disable the button instead of using a flag variable. This will offer visual clues to the user that they can't click.

Having said that, the important thing is that resetting your flag, or enabling he button, has to happen **after** `//doing all kind of stuff` is done.

Assuming that `//doing all kind of stuff` is something slow and asynchronous this means resetting it in the callback or when a promise resolves.

Here's a quick example that asynchronously runs a count. During the count `isProcessing` is set to true. In the callback function — not after it — it resets the flag.

```js
function someSlowThing(cb){
  let n = 30
  let i =  0
  let d = document.getElementById('count')
  let itv = setInterval(() => {
    if (i > n) {
      clearInterval(itv);
      i = 0
      return cb()
    } 
      d.innerHTML = i++
  }, 50)
}

var isProcessing = false;

function process(e){
 if(isProcessing) {
     console.log("wait please")
     return
  }
 isProcessing = true
 someSlowThing(() => {
     isProcessing = false // <-- important that the happens in the callback
     console.log('done')
    })
 // don't try to set isProcessing here, it will happen too soon.
}
```

```html
<div id = 'count'>0</div>
<button onclick='process()'>start</button>
```

Comment: p.s. the code above is an example of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It has enough just code that you can actually run it without wondering things like 'is "doing all kind of stuff" asynchronous?' In future questions your should provide a little more complete code — if you can make it run as a snippet, even better.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer.
i tried to apply this to my code, but after the first click it got stuck and didn't accept any new clicks.
the function cardClicked gets onclick="cardClicked(this)" from the div. tried to send it through the process function like:
function process(elCard){
    if(isProcessing) {
        console.log("wait please")
        return
     }
    isProcessing = true
    cardClicked(elCard,() => {
        isProcessing = false 
        console.log('done')
       })
    
   }